# Northern Europe equals Nordic countries, what about other position?

Tags: word-request

I just learned the word *nordic* from the Economist and am wondering what about other positions?

Could someone help me?

I can't find those words.

I googled it and could only find words like Eastern, Western, Southern Europe, which I already knew.

Is there a one word substitution for each of these words like *Nordic* to Northern Europe? 
Thank you!

Comment: One small clarification - *Nordic* doesn't mean exactly the same thing as *Northern*.  Scotland, Estonia, Latvia, and Lithuania are as far north as Denmark, but are not Nordic.  It has more to do with history and culture than strictly with geography.

Comment: Like Benelux?

Comment: Well, kind of - Benelux is a formal political arrangement, unlike either "Northern" or "Nordic", although Belgium, the Netherlands, and Luxembourg do share some cultural and linguistic similarities.

Comment: Not only does *Nordic* does not mean the same thing as *Northern Europe*, but there is no universal definition of *Northern* (or *Eastern*, *Western*, etc.); geopolitical and ethnolinguistic boundaries have shifted over time. If you want to see all the ways Europe can be subdivided, I would refer you to [Regions of Europe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regions_of_Europe) for an overview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Nordic countries are, specifically, Norway, Sweden, Denmark, Finland, and Iceland (and their associated territories).  They are called that partly because of their geographic location but mostly because of history.  As stangdon points out, Estonia, Latvia, and Lithuania are as far north as Denmark but these are referred to collectively as the *"Baltic States"* while Scotland (also in the north) is part of the United Kingdom.

Meanwhile Iceland is way over to the northwest of Ireland, but it's still considered "Nordic" because of shared cultural history.

So if you are looking for collections of countries in (and around) Europe, for example, the ["Scandinavian"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scandinavia) countries are traditionally just Denmark, Sweden, and Norway, but sometimes include Iceland, Finland, and other territories.

["The Balkans"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balkans) are the countries in the east/southeast of Europe, which currently includes Croatia, Bosnia and Herzegovina, Macedonia, Montenegro and Serbia.

["Southern Europe"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_Europe) is vague, but generally includes the regions which border the Mediterranean Sea:  Portugal, Spain, Southern France, Italy, Greece, and Malta.  Some definitions include the Balkans.

["Eastern Europe"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Europe) is similarly vague, but generally includes the nations east of the Ural Mountains, Ural River, and the Caucasus Mountains: Poland, Ukraine, Russia, Hungary, Czech Republic, Slovakia, Bulgaria, Romania, and various others.  The definition is often more political than geographic since these nations were part of the former [Warsaw Pact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warsaw_Pact), including all the nations in the former USSR.

In comparison, politically, "NATO" includes [28 nations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Member_states_of_NATO), including most of Western Europe (but not Sweden or Finland).

There are various other definitions and groupings, many cultural and/or historical, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you so much for elaborating it Andrew. I get it now.